# Simple English word that indicates the user isn't just a regular user

Tags: vocabulary

We got a 3 user roles per game:

1. Regular user
2. Recruiter
3. Admin

The user is one of the mentioned user roles per game. A user could have different user roles per game. I want to present a menu where the user sees all the games where he is the recruiter or admin. What could be the title of the this menu?

Something like 'Special' would be a bit strange. 'Recruiter or admin games' doesn't sound right as well.

Is there some easy/simple word that directly tells the user: 'This are the games that I am the recruiter/admin of'.

Comment: Perhaps "**privilege** games".

Comment: @WeatherVane hmm that is a good alternative. Although, I feel the need to create a detailed text that further explains that it lists the games which the user is recruiter/admin of. Well, maybe there isn't just 1 word for this case.

Comment: [Superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **privilege** according to the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/privilege) means

> A special right, advantage, or immunity granted or available only to a
>   particular person or group.

So perhaps your screen title could be

> Privilege Games

If the game already refers to **admin** and **recruiter** rights as "privileges" it would be self-explanatory.

Comment: Yes I though about it and this is a nice word :) Will accept it when I can